# Autofac and ASP.NET Web API ApiController

Tags: autofac, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have been using autofac with MVC 3 for a while and love it. I recently upgraded a project to MVC 4 and everything seems to be working except for Web Api ApiControllers. I am getting the following exception.

```
An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'MyNamespace.Foo.CustomApiController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.
```

This seems to me to be an issue with DI via autofac. Am I missing something or is there something in the works. I know, MVC4 just came out and is a beta so I don't expect much but figured I could be missing something.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have released Autofac integration packages on NuGet for the Beta versions of MVC 4 and Web API. The integrations will create an Autofac lifetime scope per controller request (MVC controller or API controller depending on the integration). This means that the controller and its dependencies will be automatically disposed at the end of each call. Both packages can be installed side-by-side in the same project.

**MVC 4**

https://nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Mvc4

http://alexmg.com/post/2012/03/09/Autofac-ASPNET-MVC-4-(Beta)-Integration.aspx

**Web API**

https://nuget.org/packages/Autofac.WebApi/

http://alexmg.com/post/2012/03/09/Autofac-ASPNET-Web-API-(Beta)-Integration.aspx

Links are now fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately, as of the typing of this comment, it appears that using Autofac for MVC 4 RC and Web API RC at the same time does not work. I get compiler warnings about types not being found in the Web API framework assemblies. I had to use the answer provided by @tugberk and re-implement the dependency resolver to get around it.

Answer (score 4):

I just configured this on one of my apps. There are different ways of doing it but I like this approach:

[Autofac and ASP.NET Web API System.Web.Http.Services.IDependencyResolver Integration](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/autofac-and-asp-net-web-api-system-web-http-services-idependencyresolver-integration)

First I created a class which implements `System.Web.Http.Services.IDependencyResolver` interface.

```
internal class AutofacWebAPIDependencyResolver : System.Web.Http.Services.IDependencyResolver {

    private readonly IContainer _container;

    public AutofacWebAPIDependencyResolver(IContainer container) {

        _container = container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType) {

        return _container.IsRegistered(serviceType) ? _container.Resolve(serviceType) : null;
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType) {

        Type enumerableServiceType = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(serviceType);
        object instance = _container.Resolve(enumerableServiceType);
        return ((IEnumerable)instance).Cast<object>();
    }
}
```

And I have another class which holds my registrations:

```
internal class AutofacWebAPI {

    public static void Initialize() {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.ServiceResolver.SetResolver(
            new AutofacWebAPIDependencyResolver(RegisterServices(builder))
        );
    }

    private static IContainer RegisterServices(ContainerBuilder builder) {

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly).PropertiesAutowired();

        builder.RegisterType<WordRepository>().As<IWordRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<MeaningRepository>().As<IMeaningRepository>();

        return
            builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Then, initialize it at `Application_Start`:

```
protected void Application_Start() {

    //...

    AutofacWebAPI.Initialize();

    //...
}
```

I hope this helps.