# AutoFac does not register api controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, repository-pattern, autofac

I am using AutoFac to registered api controller but don't know whats the problem

Getting error

```
Type 'myApp.WebAPI.Controllers.myController' does not have a default constructor
```

I added IocHelper class as below

```
public class IocHelper {
public static IContainer CreateContainer() {

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        var container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        return container;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you invoking `IocHelper.CreateContainer`?

Comment: Yes, I call `IocHelper.CreateContainer( );`  in startup.cs class.

Comment: Is this all your container registration code? Where do you register the dependencies of your controllers?

Comment: Do you setup web api in startup.cs or in Global.asax? Can we see the startup.cs file ?

Comment: Solve the problem thanks to all.

I am doing a lot of thing in startup.cs file with owin hence by calling Iocahelper in startup.cs, I normally registered my all module in startup.cs file only and change this :


    `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container); `


to :


    `config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);`

and added this also :

    `appBuilder.UseAutofacWebApi(config);`

Answer (score 0):

```
    Please refer the below solution, and also make sure you declared the injected interfaces as public explicitly.
    //Global.asax file -Application Start method
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
             var bootStrapApp = new BootstrapApplication()
            .ConfigureRoute(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)
            .ConfigureContainer(new ContainerBuilder(), GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    }

    // BootstrapApplication.cs class file

    public class BootstrapApplication
    {
       public BootstrapApplication ConfigureRoute(HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration)
       {

          httpConfiguration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
          return this;
       }

      public BootstrapApplication ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder container, HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration)
      {
        var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(n => n.FullName.StartsWith("<projectNamespacevalue>")).ToArray();
        //projectNamespacevalue for ex. AspNet.WebApi2.Demo 
        // var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(n => n.FullName.StartsWith("AspNet")).ToArray();

        container.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies).AsImplementedInterfaces();
        container.RegisterApiControllers(assemblies); //WebApi controllers scanning and registration
        var ioccontainer = container.Build();
        httpConfiguration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(ioccontainer);      
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add more details how this would solve the problem?